# cakephp file field validation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i m trying to validate file field in cakephp in model with valid extension on create and on update try to validate file only if field is not empty.On Create the validation works fine, But on update it validates the if field is empty.I want to validate extensions only when the field is not empty
here is my validation rule in model validation array

```
'image' => array(
        'rule1'=>array(
            'rule' => array('extension',array('jpeg','jpg','png','gif')),
            'required' => 'create',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'message' => 'Select Valid Image',
            'on' => 'create',
            'last'=>true
        ),
        'rule2'=>array(
            'rule' => array('extension',array('jpeg','jpg','png','gif')),
            //'required' => 'create',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'message' => 'Select Valid Image',
            'on' => 'update',
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Are you using a plugin? If so, include that info in your question. If not, consider using one, such as https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload

Comment: No, I am not using any plugin,but i use models beforeSave method to upload and process files

Answer (score 4):

Here is the correct way to validate image field with required on create and can allow empty on update of image field

**Image Field Validation Array**

```
'image' => array(
    'rule1'=>array(
        'rule' => array('extension',array('jpeg','jpg','png','gif')),
        'required' => 'create',
        'allowEmpty' => true,
        'message' => 'Select Valid Image',
        'on' => 'create',
        'last'=>true
    ),
    'rule2'=>array(
        'rule' => array('extension',array('jpeg','jpg','png','gif')),
        'message' => 'Select Valid Image',
        'on' => 'update',
    ),
),
```

**And unset the image field on in beforevalidation in update action**

```
function beforeValidate($options = array()){
    if(empty($this->data[$this->alias]['id']))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(empty($this->data[$this->alias]["image"]["name"])){
        unset($this->data[$this->alias]["image"]);
        }
        return true; //this is required, otherwise validation will always fail
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do it by Custom validation as follows

```
public $validate =array(
    'image' => array(
        'rule' => array('checkValidImage'),
        )
    );


 public function checkValidImage($field)
      {

        $extension = array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/x-png', 'image/png', 'image/jpg');
        $isValidFile = in_array($field['new_image']['type'], $extension);
        $errors = array();
        $editMethod = false;
        if(!empty($this->data['ModelName']['id'])) // It will work for Update Method
        {
          if(!empty($this->data['ModelName']['image']['name'] ))
          {
            if (($field['image']['error'] == 1)) 
            {
                $errors [] = "Please upload jpg,png or gif files with size 2 MB.";
            }
            else if (empty($field['image']['name']))
            {
                $errors [] = "Please upload image";
            } 
            else if ($field['image']['size'] >= 2097152) {
                $errors [] = "Please upload jpg,png or gif files with size 2 MB.";
            }
            else if ($isValidFile !=1)
            {

                $errors [] = "Please select file in gif,jpeg,png format.";
            }

          }else
                {
                    $errors [] = "Please select file in gif,jpeg,png format.";
                }

        }
        else
        {
            if(!empty($this->data['ModelName']['image']['name'] )) // It will work for Create Method
            {
                if (($field['image']['error'] == 1)) 
                {
                    $errors [] = "Please upload jpg,png or gif files with size 2 MB.";
                }
                else if (empty($field['ModelName']['name']))
                {
                    $errors [] = "Please upload image";
                } 
                else if ($field['ModelName']['size'] >= 2097152) {
                    $errors [] = "Please upload jpg,png or gif files with size 2 MB.";
                }
                else if (!(in_array($field['image']['type'], $extension)))
                {
                    $errors [] = "Please select file in gif,jpeg,png format.";
                }

            }



        }

        if (!empty($errors))
        {
            return implode("\n", $errors);
        }
        return true;
    }
```