# CakePHP Model Validation

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I have a simple form in CakePHP.

I want to upload image and want to define CakePHP Validation on recent_picture.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('MyController', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->file('recent_picture'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Create Account & Continue')); ?>
```

I have define Validation in model.

```
     public $validate = array(
        'recent_picture' => array(
            'rule'    => array(
            'extension',
            array('gif', 'jpeg', 'png', 'jpg')
            ),
            'message' => 'Please supply a valid image.'
        ),  
    );
```

The Above Validation works and gives error if I did not fill it. But it did not validate on image extension.

So Please Help me.

Any Help Will be Appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cakephp file field validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583358/cakephp-file-field-validation)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why its not working as it was not working for me either (I followed docs like you probably ) just a day or two ago and itsead for struggling I chose a way arround. Maybe thats not the best answer, and not clean one but you can validiate extension just after you upload it with something like this:

```
$mime_type_correct = preg_match("/image\/*\w+/", $file_data['type']);
```

Hope that will help you.
PS: this snippet may also come in handy for you:

```
        switch ($file_data['error']) {
        case 0:
            //no error
            break;
        case 1:
            $err_msg = __('The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize');
            $error = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            $err_msg = __('The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE from form');
            $error = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            $error_msg = __('The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.');
            $error = true;
            break;
        case 4:
            $err_msg = __('No file was uploaded.');
            $error = true;
            break;
        case 6:
            $err_msg = __('Missing a temporary folder.');
            $error = true;
            break;
        case 7:
            $err_msg = __('Failed to write file to disk.');
            $error = true;
            break;
        case 8:
            $err_msg = __('A PHP extension stopped the file upload.');
            $error = true;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```