# Allow no file when validation an uploaded file - CakePHP 2

Tags: php, file, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm uploading an image for an article, and in the model, i set some validation rules for this image.

```
//View
$this->Form->input('Post.image');

//Model Post
public $validate = array(
    'image' => array(
        'extension' => array(
            'rule' => array('extension', array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp')),
            'message' => "L'extension de l'image envoyée n'est pas valide"
        ),
        'uploadError' => array(
            'rule' => array('uploadError', true),
            'message' => "Une erreur est survenue lors de l'upload de l'image"
        ),
        'mimeType' => array(
            'rule' => array('mimeType', array('image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/bmp')),
            'message' => "Type de l'image invalide"
        ),
        'fileSize' => array(
            'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '2MB'),
            'message' => "La taille de l'image ne doit pas dépasser 2MB"
        )
    )
);
```

The image is not `required`, but the input generated in html view contains the `required` attribute, i fix that by adding `allowEmpty => true` on every rule. But still, the validation doesnt pass!

How can i fix this ?

Thank you

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583358/cakephp-file-field-validation

Comment: Your `$this->Form->create();` has `type="file"` in second argument (in array)?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you include a `'required' => false` instead of using `'allowEmpty' => true`? Based on how I understood the [CookBook regarding allowEmpty](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#allowempty), it checks by running a `!empty($value) || is_numeric($value)` whereas submitting a File input would result to an array. Hence the `$value` would still be true and still required given the current validation rules.

Hope that was at the very least, help you in any way.